# RemoteTransportException Failed to deserialize exception response from stream Elastic Search Java API

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Java Code for inserting document into elastic search

```
Client client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300));
        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        json.put("user","dummy");
        json.put("name","dumm");
        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.prepareIndex("myindex", "mytype").setSource(json).execute().actionGet();
        System.out.println(indexResponse.toString());
```

Response of: http://localhost:9200/_nodes?jvm=true

```
"pid": ​6797,
"version": "1.8.0_77",
"vm_name": "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
"vm_version": "25.77-b03",
"vm_vendor": "Oracle Corporation",
```

Reesponse of  http://localhost:9200:

```
{

    "status": ​200,
    "name": "Sin",
    "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
    "version": 

    {
        "number": "1.6.2",
        "build_hash": "622039121e53e5f520b5ff8720fdbd3d0cb5326b",
        "build_timestamp": "2015-07-29T09:24:47Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "4.10.4"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"

}
```

depedency added via maven:

```
 org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.5.0
```

I am compiling using 1.8.0_77 to compile my source code but still getting the following exception. This type of exception occur when there is version mismatch but I don't have any

```
  2016-05-06 13:33:15  INFO [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (Log4jESLogger.java:104) - [Josten, Conrad] loaded [], sites []
     2016-05-06 13:33:16  WARN [elasticsearch[Josten, Conrad][transport_client_worker][T#1]{New I/O worker #1}] (Log4jESLogger.java:114) - [Josten, Conrad] Message not fully read (response) for [0] handler future(org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler$1@52d6882a), error [true], resetting
     2016-05-06 13:33:16  INFO [http-bio-8080-exec-1] (Log4jESLogger.java:109) - [Josten, Conrad] failed to get node info for [#transport#-1][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]], disconnecting...
     org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:171)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1603)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:169)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
```

Comment: If your cluster uses version `1.6.2` why do you import `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:1.5.0`? Use the **same version as the cluster**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a conflict between two versions of elastic jar. The 1.5.0 version was omitted by maven automatically because 0.5 was in the lib and it depends on build order of modules.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that ElasticsearchException class is not found, see the last 2 lines in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The elastacsearch version is 1.6.2 ,but you import 1.5.0 jar dependency into maven. This maybe the problem.